# Lists of Jewish Hotlines

Tags: product-recommendation, adult-learning

I do not own a smartphone, and it is easier to listen to recordings of shiurim and music over the phone. I am looking for a list of Jewish Hotlines, specifically for more gemara or english shiurim.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few I know. Please share if you know anymore!

- Rambam over the telephone: 718-480-0200
- Chassidus over the telephone: 718-735-7333
- Kol Halashon: 718-521-5231
- TheYeshiva.net: 845-201-1933
- TorahPhone (subscription): 718-436-3846

Answer (score 1):

Torah Anytime: +1 718-298-2077

Voice News: +1 605-562-1616
Voice News is mostly News. But it does have Zemanim and Jewish music. But no Torah.

Tznius Hotline [women]: +1 718-907-6888

[I wonder if this is the kind of question that Mi Yodeya is for.]

Answer (score 0):

chazak hotline

The Loop

Izzy and dizzy hotline

Pirchei hotline

KOL HALASHON (718)-906-6400 - It has almost anything you want

For all the numbers, check online.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Nissan and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!